# Force click propagation from Vis network to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dom-events

I have a [Vis Network](http://visjs.org/) div on top of a Google maps div. I used absolute positioning to get one above the other. The idea is to show a graph geo positioned on top of the map.

So far I managed to handle this pretty well by translating events on the network (top layer) to the Google maps (bottom layer), like dragging and zooming. But now I really got stuck:

I use Fusion Tables to draw a layer on Google maps and I need to add click events to this layer. The problem is I can't see a way to translate a click in a pos x/y of the network to a click on a specific polygon on the layer of Google maps.

**Is there a way to force the propagation from the network (top layer) to the map (bottom layer)?**

Note: I need the main interaction to be on the network, so inverting the layers order is not an option.